# How can I execute a method in a device from an Azure function in C#?

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I have a Stream Analytics that depending on what it recives it outputs some data to an Azure function in C#. This functions must send a JSON to the device and when this reads the JSON it runs a local method depending on the data received. My problem is that I cant find the way to do this.

I have already done this in Java but I can't find the way to do it in C#. The way that I do this is with a HTTP trigger and the code below.

This is how I deserialize the received data:

```
String body = request.getBody().get().toString().replace("[", "").replace("\"", "\'");
JSONObject bodyJson = new JSONObject(body);

String deviceMac = bodyJson.getString("deviceid");
deviceId = bodyJson.getString("receiveruuid");
```

And this is how I send the result to the device:

```
DeviceMethod methodClient = DeviceMethod.createFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
{
    //PAYLOAD DATA
}};
MethodResult result = methodClient.invoke(deviceId, methodName, responseTimeout, connectTimeout, payload);
```

Thank you for your help

---

**UPDATE**

**I finally resolved the problem** in this way.

```
        var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
        var methodname = new CloudToDeviceMethod("method_defatult").SetPayloadJson(" {\"message\": \""+ message +"\"}");
        await serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync("moviltest", methodname);
```

With the **first line** you create the connection string to the iotHub. The second line is creates the CloudToDeviceMethod and also you set the payload. Make sure that the JSON is correct. **Finally** it invokes the method in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally resolved the problem in this way.**

```
    var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
    var methodname = new CloudToDeviceMethod("method_defatult").SetPayloadJson(" {\"message\": \""+ message +"\"}");
    await serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync("moviltest", methodname);
```

With the first line you create the connection string to the iotHub. The second line is creates the CloudToDeviceMethod and also you set the payload. Make sure that the JSON is correct. Finally it invokes the method in the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the bytes from the message and send it to the device:

```
private async static Task SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync()
{
    var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
    var commandMessage = new
    Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cloud to device message."));
    await serviceClient.SendAsync("myFirstDevice", commandMessage);
}
```

more info in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d